# Cache files permissions fix for Kohana Twig module

Tags: caching, twig, kohana, file-permissions

How to configure [Kohana + Twig](https://github.com/tommcdo/kohana-twig) module so the Twig will set *"writable by all"* permissions on all of it's cache directory and it's descendant files?

So, for example, when I run my application through the [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) module (`mod_php`) and cache file owner is `apache` (or `httpd`) user, I will be able to remove cache files (to clean the cache or completely remove whole application) using regular user and `ssh` access.

I'm able to do it with Kohana's cache, but Twig's cache is created somehow differently.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very easy, but not too complicated either. I have achieved state presented below by trial-and-error method.

1. Create a class that inherits from `Twig_Cache_Filesystem` and will be used **instead** of it. Check this out:

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Application\Twig;

   class Cache_Filesystem extends \Twig_Cache_Filesystem
   {
       public function write($key, $content)
       {
           $old = umask(0000);
           parent::write($key, $content);
           umask($old);
       }
   }
   ```

   Note, that this class must have it's name unique, so it is a good idea to namespace it. Also, it must be accessible to other code, so consider using `composer`'s autoloading feature.

   This is the fix itself, rest of the guide is just the way of implementing it into Kohana+Twig ecosystem.
2. Copy `Twig.php` from `modules/kohana-twig/classes/Twig.php` into your application's directory, i.e. `application/classes/Twig.php` (thank you [Kohana's Cascading Filesystem](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/files)!)
3. Modify a bit newly copied file, to let `Twig_CacheInterface` instance be passed in the config file (`application/config/twig.php`) instead of just a simple string (specifying to the Twig's cache directory). Take a look of my example:

   ```
   <?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

   class Twig extends Kohana_Twig
   {
       /**
        * Initialize the Twig module
        *
        * @throws Kohana_Exception
        * @return bool
        */
       public static function init()
       {
           $path = Kohana::$config->load('twig.environment.cache');
           if (is_string($path)) {
               return parent::init();
           } else if ($path instanceof Twig_CacheInterface) {
               return true;
           }

           throw new Kohana_Exception('Twig cache could not be initialized');
       }

   }
   ```
4. In configuration file for `kohana-twig` module, i.e. `application/config/twig.php` (if not yet copied from module to your application, do it now), define `environment.cache` key like this:

   ```
   return array(

       'loader' => array(
           'extension' => 'twig',
           'path' => 'views',
       ),
       'environment' => array(
           'auto_reload' => (Kohana::$environment >= Kohana::TESTING),
           'autoescape' => true,
           'base_template_class' => 'Twig_Template',
           // Following line is related to this issue and fix:
           'cache' => new \Application\Twig\Cache_Filesystem(APPPATH . 'cache/twig'),
           'charset' => 'utf-8',
           'optimizations' => - 1,
           'strict_variables' => false,
       ),
       'functions' => array(),
       'filters' => array(),
       'tests' => array(),
   }
   ```

This works for me. Hopefully it will help someone struggling with similar problem.